# image block my clickable div

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have an mouse over function in javascript, and a clickable div, the thing is that when Im clicking on the image, nothing happends, but outside the image its works perfectly.

```
   <div id="1" onclick="SendRating(this.id);" onmouseover="rateStar(this.id)" ><img src="star.jpg"></div>
```

and my mouse over function.

```
function rateStar(rating){
    var i = 1;
    var ratings = '';
    for (i==1; i<=5; i++){
        if (i<=rating){
            document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = '<img src="star1.gif">';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = '<img src="star.jpg">';
        }
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs cannot start with numbers. Make your code:

```
<div id="rating_1" score='1' onclick="SendRating(this.getAttribute('score'));" onmouseover="rateStar(this.id)" ><img src="star.jpg"></div>
```

and change your javascript to

```
function rateStar(rating){
    var i = 1;
    var ratings = '';
    for (i==1; i<=5; i++){
        if (i<=rating){
            document.getElementById('rating_'+i).innerHTML = '<img src="star1.gif">';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('rating_'+i).innerHTML = '<img src="star.jpg">';
        }
    }
}
```

This may not solve your issue, but you need to do it in any case. Also, think about moving the onclick event to the image itself:

```
<div><img src="star.jpg" score='1' id="rating_1" onclick="SendRating(this.getAttribute('score'));" ></div>
```

and changing your js to:

```
 function rateStar(rating){
        var i = 1;
        var ratings = '';
        for (i==1; i<=5; i++){
            if (i<=rating){
                document.getElementById('rating_'+i).src= 'star1.gif';
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById('rating_'+i).src= 'star.jpg';
            }
        }
    }
```

So you're just changing the image source